# The graphql request works on Chrome, but will be aborted on IE11?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Currently I am working on a graphql project, in which we employ react-relay for front-end.

After deploying and building, I found that the ajax request is good on Chrome(v64) as the screenshot below.
[successful on Chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4J0K.jpg)

But the same request will be aborted by IE(v11). That's weird. 
[aborted on IE screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ou6N.png)

I guess it could be a babel-pollyfill problem. But I need help from you genius.